# Cell Formatting, 0.00 where blank value

Tags: microsoft-excel, date-time, cell-format

I have some cells that are formatted as hours and minutes i.e. `[h]:mm`.

If no value exists in a cell I want the cell to show **0:00** without having to manually type.

It needs to be user friendly, so if I copy cells from another spreadsheet and there are no values the **0:00** should not become blank.

Comment: You can make it for cells where you have a value of `0`. But I think you cannot do it for cells which are blank, i.e. no value at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Find and Replace:

Ctrl+F to bring up the Find and Replace box
Leave "Find what:" blank
Click on the replace tab and type 0:00 in the "Replace with:" box
Click Replace all

If you want this applied to only a certain column, hihglight the column before replacing all